# Semantic Web - Are Turtle and JSON-LD the same thing - a way to save RDF

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, json-ld, turtle-rdf

I've just started looking at Semantic Web and there's one thing I'm a little uncertain of:

Are Turtle, JSON-LD (and others like Trig) simply ways to write RDF in their own respective syntaxes?

From what I understand once its in some RDF format, I can happily run SPARQL queries - or is there more to their differences, like specific use cases?

Regards.

Comment: Yes, those are just different syntaxes to serialize RDF. Like also N-Triples, RDF/XML. And yes, you can run SPARQL queries once you loaded the RDF data into the triple store/SPARQL engine of your choice - the only limitation might be that one of the syntax formats isn't supported by the triple store. although this is very rare especially for the most popular ones.

Comment: Trig is a bit different from the other formats as it allows to serialize whole datasets, i.e. it can contain multiple graphs with its contained triples. Same for N-Quads format.

Comment: https://w3c.github.io/json-ld-syntax/#relationship-to-rdf. JSON-LD allows predicates to be blank nodes :).

Comment: ok, so it's [generalized RDF](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#section-generalized-rdf) which is afaik non-standard though

Answer (score 1):

RDF-Turtle and JSON-LD are really notations for inscribing RDF sentences to documents.

RDF Documents may reside on a Filesystem or be managed by a DBMS, Quad- or Triple-store.

SPARQL is a Declarative Query Language for performing Data Definition and Data Manipulation operations on Data Represented in RDF (i.e., Relations represented as subject->predicate->object 3-tuples).

SPARQL is handled by a SPARQL Processor (or Engine) that is typically a feature of an RDF-supporting DBMS, Quad- or Triple store.

You ability to use SPARQL is totally unaffected by your RDF being created using RDF-Turtle or JSON-LD notations.

One final thing, the body of a SPARQL Query is actually RDF-Turtle plus additional support of variables as another mechanism for entity denotation.